# Developing a quiz web application Using Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

In my application, I have 2 options one is host the quiz and one is join the quiz.

When we host a quiz random code will be generated and then he/she should pass on the code such that the participant will join the quiz.

Which concept in Angular to be used here?

Comment: can u explain in more detail. I can help u

Comment: is it having any backend api?

Comment: Yes...there is backend api..from there we retrieve questions and answers..my question is how to develop it with like multiplayer functionality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want real time system?

Use **socket.io**
https://socket.io/

It is very simple and useful library to implement realtime system such as chatting.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is use a random function to generate a token. One copy of token you keep and the other you provide to the user. If both of them matches start the quiz.

Comment: how to check whether that token matches or not ?

Comment: one token will be there in the component where it is generated. and u can also store it in local storage  localStorage.setItem('Token',<tokenValue>). once u have this ready u just have to pass value from UI through ngModel to component and match the token

Answer (score 2):

One thing u can also do if are using multi played function. add Session data store. Or if u want more advance use socket connection. between API and UI.

Use socket.io
https://socket.io/